# Changing required status of GraphQL input fields

Tags: graphql

The GraphQL [docs](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) indicate that a way of applying [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) in the schema is to use `input` types for objects, here's the message example:

```
input MessageInput {
  content: String
  author: String
}

type Message {
  id: ID!
  content: String
  author: String
}

type Query {
  getMessage(id: ID!): Message
}

type Mutation {
  createMessage(input: MessageInput): Message
  updateMessage(id: ID!, input: MessageInput): Message
}
```

My issue with this approach is that I will still have to do on the server validation for required elements, e.g. if I want *both* content and author to be present in the `createMessage` I only require one of them for the update function. An alternative is to have all fields required regardless of create/update, i.e. forcing the user to re-send the data.

**Question:** Is there a recommended approach to specify/implement an input type that is shared by create/update?